# dtmTime in VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to convert this line of code:

```
     dtmTime As New DateTime
```

from VB to C#. If I'm not mistaken C# doesn't have a DateTime function. I'm only declaring a variable and then using it here:

```
    if (Date.Today.ToString.Contains("PM"))
```

Comment: C# definitely has a DateTime class.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Maybe you should give this a read : http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime

Comment: @nbokmans: Well no, it has a DateTime *struct*... where "it" is .NET, rather than C#...

Comment: Your VB will not compile without a Dim statement before it. Also do yourself a favour and don't ever test for afternoon using a string.contains, just check `myDate.Hour >= 12`

Comment: VB and C# are both built on the .NET Framework, which means they both have access to the same base classes. DateTime and any other class you're instantiating in VB is available to you in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a string is not a good idea.  You can do all your date math/logic using the `DateTime` type itself.  For instance:

```
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0)) //...
```

or even shorter:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12) //...
```

Either of these will tell you if the current time is after 12:00 PM.

Comment: You probably want `>=` rather than `>` - and just `DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12` is somewhat simpler.